# How do you print a class's attributes by the objects name using java?

Tags: java, python

In Python if you want to print a string representation of a class's attributes you would define something like

```
class building:
   def __init__(self,type,height):
       self.type = type
       self.height = height

    def __str__():
        return "i am a %s and i am {:%.1f} meters tall", (type,height)

hospital = Building()
hospital.type = "Medical Facility"
hospital.height = 30

print(hospital)
>>> i am a Medical Facility and i am 30.0 meters tall
```

Does java have the equivalent of a python `__str__`? If not how can I achieve the output above?

Comment: I guess you are looking for [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class, where you can pass dynamic values to the `String`

Comment: It's called `toString()` in java. Just implement (it's actually a **override**) `public String toString() {return "Whatever";}` and you will be good to go..

Comment: FWIW, your `__str__()` method is very broken.

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't doubt it. I usually use the new style .format. No idea why I tried to use that in an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the "toString()". I think it's the same with the **str()** in python

```
public class Employee {
    public int id;
    public String fName;
    public String mName;

public Employee(int id, String fName, String mName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.fName = fName;
    this.mName = mName;
}




@Override
public String toString() {
    String output = "Hello, I am employee " + id + ", my first name is " + fName + " and my middle name is " + mName;
    return output;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee e= new Employee(1, "foo" ,"bar");
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
}
```